# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

i am trying to submit a simple login form but the server keep responding with "Request method 'POST' not supported" as a warning.and the problem is not that the form acion is not responding ,in fact the methode respond and do the traitment but can not return the result and that where i get this warning.

i already tried mapping the controller method by "RequestMethod.POST", but it didn't make any difference

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class HomeController {


    @Autowired
    Iuserservice userservice;


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method =RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        USER_PARAM user = new USER_PARAM();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);



        return "pages/login";
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param user
     * @param result
     * @param status
     * @return
     */
     @RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
        public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") USER_PARAM user,
                                BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
        {
         //Validation code start
            boolean error = false;

            System.out.println(user); //Verifying if information is same as input by user


            //on verifie est ce que les champs sont pas vide

            //user name
            if(user.getUSER_NAME().isEmpty()){
                result.rejectValue("USER NAME", "error.USER_NAME");
                error = true;
            }
             // user password
            if(user.getUSER_PASSWORD().isEmpty()){
                result.rejectValue("USER PASSWORD", "error.USER_PASSWORD");
                error = true;
            }

            // si error est true: on renvoie vers la page login avec des message d'erreur 
            if(error)  return "pages/login";

            // si un enregistrement identique est deja presen : on renvoie vers la page login avec des message d'erreur 
            if (userservice.login(user)==null)  return "pages/login";   


            // si l'aithentification a marcher : on renvoie vers la page index
            else {
                System.out.println("------------154");
                return "index";
                }


        }



}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html class="bg-black">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>AdminLTE | Log in</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="bg-black">

        <div class="form-box" id="login-box">
            <div class="header"><spring:message code="lbl.page" text="Sign in" /></div>
            <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">
                <div class="body bg-gray">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <spring:message code="lbl.USER_NAME" text="USER NAME" />
                    <form:input path="USER_NAME"  class="form-control" placeholder="USER NAME"/>
                    <form:errors path="USER_NAME" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <spring:message code="lbl.USER_PASSWORD" text="USER PASSWORD" />
                    <form:input path="USER_PASSWORD"  class="form-control" placeholder="USER PASSWORD" type="password" />
                    <form:errors path="USER_PASSWORD" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>          
                   <!--   
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"/> Remember me
                    </div>
                    -->
                </div>
                <div class="footer">                                                               
                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">
                    <spring:message code="lbl.submit" text="Sign me in" />
                    </button>  

                    <%--<p><a href="#">I forgot my password</a></p>--%>

                    <a href="register" class="text-center">
                    <spring:message code="lbl.register" text="Register a new membership" />                    
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form:form>

        </div>


        <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

    </body>
</html>
```

**servelet-context.xml**

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="app.controller, app.dao.impl, app.service.impl, app.dao, app.service" />
```

**what showed in the console**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:29:50 WEST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [infrastructure-config/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 694 ms
juil. 24, 2019 11:29:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:29:51 WEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [infrastructure-config/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/ajax/dashboard-boxrefresh-demo],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.controller.AjaxController.refreshDashBoard(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/decorators/{decorator}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.controller.DecoratorController.pages(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.controller.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET || POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String app.controller.HomeController.login(app.model.USER_PARAM,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:29:51 WEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:29:51 WEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions (file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/apps/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 4739 ms
juil. 24, 2019 11:29:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
juil. 24, 2019 11:29:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
juil. 24, 2019 11:29:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9620 ms
app.model.USER_PARAM@1cf59d9
WARN : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 43.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
Hibernate: select user_param0_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_0_, user_param0_.BLOCK_ACCESS as BLOCK_AC2_0_, user_param0_.COMPLEXITY_FLAG as COMPLEXI3_0_, user_param0_.CONNECTED as CONNECTE4_0_, user_param0_.DATE_END_PASS as DATE_END5_0_, user_param0_.DATE_START_PASS as DATE_STA6_0_, user_param0_.EXPIRATION_PASSWORD as EXPIRATI7_0_, user_param0_.FIRST_CONNECTION as FIRST_CO8_0_, user_param0_.IP_ADDRESS as IP_ADDRE9_0_, user_param0_.IP_ADDRESS_MANG as IP_ADDR10_0_, user_param0_.LANGUAGE_CODE as LANGUAG11_0_, user_param0_.LAST_4_PWD as LAST_12_0_, user_param0_.LENGTH_PASSWORD as LENGTH_13_0_, user_param0_.NBRE_SEESION_CONNECTED as NBRE_SE14_0_, user_param0_.NBRE_SESSION_ALLOWED as NBRE_SE15_0_, user_param0_.NUMBER_OF_TRIES as NUMBER_16_0_, user_param0_.NUMBER_OF_TRIES_ALLOWED as NUMBER_17_0_, user_param0_.USER_BANK_CODE as USER_BA18_0_, user_param0_.USER_BRANCH_CODE as USER_BR19_0_, user_param0_.USER_CODE as USER_CO20_0_, user_param0_.USER_NAME as USER_NA21_0_, user_param0_.USER_PASSWORD as USER_PA22_0_, user_param0_.USER_TYPE as USER_TY23_0_ from USER_PARAM user_param0_ where user_param0_.USER_NAME=?
app.model.USER_PARAM@45c0e7e9
------------154
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

**what i am getting as respond in my navigator**

[image: what i am getting as respond in my navigator]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is clear you should separate your `login` method in two. One of them should be with `RequestMethod.POST` and another with `RequestMethod.GET`. Your solution can cause unexpected behavior, and it is a good practice to write it separately

Comment: thanks for you respond @Vsevolod Mitckevich .i have tried what you said and deleted `RequestMethod.GET` and let only `RequestMethod.POST` but still no difference.

Comment: @mohamedelghaouth, also you should check your URLs. I can't find `/apps/` part in your controllers, there is only `/login`

Comment: your first advice was the solution, i created two method one for GET and one for POST.and it work now. thanks :)